# Windows installing pytorch 0.3

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, torchvision

I need to install pytorch==0.3 (I'm using conda), but when I run the command line, conda says that the needed packages are not available. Is there a way I can install it (possibly without using ubuntu)?

Comment: `Note: most pytorch versions are available only for specific CUDA versions. For example pytorch=1.0.1 is not available for CUDA 9.2` that's what it says on their [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/). Could this be your problem?

Comment: I have no cuda, so I followed the command line "without cuda": 
_conda install pytorch==0.3.0 torchvision -c pytorch_

Comment: Can you try using pip? Or is conda absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 2):

peterjc123 released the version for windows here: https://anaconda.org/peterjc123/pytorch

Answer (score 1):

The earliest available version on windows is 0.4.0
As can be seen when searching for the available version on conda.

```
$conda search pytorch-cpu -c pytorch
Loading channels: done
# Name                  Version           Build  Channel
pytorch-cpu               0.4.0 py35_cpuhe774522_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               0.4.0 py36_cpuhe774522_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               0.4.1 py35_cpuhe774522_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               0.4.1 py36_cpuhe774522_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               0.4.1 py37_cpuhe774522_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.0     py3.5_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.0     py3.6_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.0     py3.7_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.1     py3.5_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.1   py3.6.7_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.1     py3.6_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.1   py3.7.1_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.0.1     py3.7_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.1.0     py3.5_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.1.0     py3.6_cpu_1  pytorch
pytorch-cpu               1.1.0     py3.7_cpu_1  pytorch
```

And on the release page of version 0.4.0 https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.0

If you want to use version 0.3.0 I suggest you use a linux or mac operating system.